# gh CLI, how to force a pull request title to the name of the branch?

Tags: github, command-line-interface

`gh pr create` is being integrated into our workflow, currently being used in interactive mode.

Yet, we observe the following behaviour:

- From an "empty" topic branch (i.e. the topic branch HEAD is also `develop` HEAD): `gh pr create` does not offer a default title.
- From a "single-commit" topic branch: `gh pr create` proposes the commit's message as the default PR title.
- From a several commits topic branch: `gh pr create` proposes the branch's name as the default PR title.

Is there a way to ask the `gh` tool to use the branch's name in all situations?

---

**Edit**: @bk2204 raises the option of explicitly providing the title from arbitrary subshell computation. It is a good improvment, sadly, it would not be a "default title" anymore, in the sense that the interactive process of `gh pr create` would not offer to override this title anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe this is the default behavior of the GitHub interface for a PR if you don't specify a title at all.  In other words, because you haven't specified a title explicitly, it picked the value it would have picked as if you opened the PR in the web interface.

If you want to always use the branch name as the title, then you can use the `-t` option like so:

```
$ gh pr create -t "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
```

The part in the command substitution provides the branch name if you are on a branch.  You could add additional commands if you want to replace dashes with spaces or such, and you could create a suitable alias if you like.

I will point out that in many environments, the branch name is not an especially good PR title.  Sometimes people place their initials or username in the branch, which is probably not relevant for a PR title.  I personally am very bad at naming branches and so I will always end up wanting to edit the title.  There are various other reasons to adopt a different approach as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use a subshell, and the rationale! The branch name is not always the best solution, but in our specific environment, the branch name is automatically derived from the issue it addresses, so it is the best default for the matching PR tiltle. Something that was great with `gh pr create` default is that it could still be explicitly overriden if needed. This ability is lost by "hardcoding a custom default" with `-t` though (i.e., it is not a default anymore ; ).

Comment: There is no way to ask GitHub to use a different default, as far as I'm aware.